# Why does my program return the first inputted value without the decimal every run?

Tags: c, for-loop, int, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int count, value;
    double avg, sum;
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    printf("please input how many integers you have \n");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("please input your values \n");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        sum = sum + value;
    }
    avg = sum / count;
    printf("your average is " "%f", avg);
}
```

Example: count input is `4`. input values is `7.6, 1, 2, 3`.

I understand that in the for loop `scanf` sees `7.6` first, but disregards the decimal point as it is not a valid form of input, and passes it along every subsequent `scanf` in the loop though they never truly accept an input. This results in the only inputted value as 7, but then the program should continue to divide 7 by 4 to retrieve the "Expected" average, but that is not the case. I end up with 7.000000, which I can't figure out why is happening.

Disregard the fact that I am prompting the user to input integer values even though floating point values were inputted because it is part of my homework assignment. Any hints or references to what I should study would be great

Comment: `scanf("%d", &value);` --> `scanf("%lf", &value);`

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that in the for loop scanf sees 7.6 first, but disregards the decimal point [..]

No. That's a matching failure as the input you enter (`7.6`) doesn't match the format specifier `%d`. Hence, `scanf()` fails. That's why you should always check the return code of all the standard functions. See [7.21.6.2 The fscanf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p4).

If you want to be able to read floating point values then you should read (change your code) to read floats (or doubles).

For example to read a `double`:

```
double value;
if (scanf("%lfd", &value) != 1) {
   /* handle failure */
}
```

A general suggestion: Don't use `scanf()` if at all possible. Please read [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) for further explanation.

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, but I'm pretty sure that's not undefined behaviour. If the type of the variable didn't match the format specifier, then sure, but the format specifier was `%d` and the type was `int`. The input not matching the format given should just result in a matching failure, and make `scanf` return early with a smaller return value, as far as I can see - and in this case, on the first time, it should match up to the period. (If you disagree, I would very much like a pointer to the part of the standard that supposedly makes it undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning seems to be correct, except for the assumption that `scanf` will set `value` to zero on the subsequent iterations. Instead, after reading up to the period on the first iteration and assigning 7 to `value`, on subsequent iterations `scanf` will see the period, conclude that the input doesn't match the format, and not touch `value` at all, leaving it as 7 on every iteration. (It should return 1 on the first iteration and 0 on subsequent ones, to indicate the number of items matched and assigned)

So, the loop will add 7 on every iteration, and then divide by the number of iterations, giving a result of 7.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and it's indeed a matching failure (which is not undefined behaviour). I stand corrected. +1!